# Google Chrome Update Causes Links In New Window To Be Very Small

Tags: google-chrome, external-links

When i click on an external link (ie a link which opens in a new window) on the project i am working on, the new window is tiny...

has anyone else encountered this issue?

it's Chrome 25.0.1364.97 m with Windows 7.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://youtu.be/uvoZEN-fJoY?hd=1','youtubewindow', 'fullscreen=yes, scrollbars=auto');">
```

**EDIT**

Fixed now,

could not find the underlying issue so replaced:

```
'fullscreen=yes, scrollbars=auto'
```

With:

`'fullscreen=yes, scrollbars=yes, width=750, height=750'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying issue is with Chrome 25.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=178440.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the latest version of chrome specifically for this question but cannot reproduce your problem. What version of Chrome are you using? What OS? Could you paste the code or link to where the problem persists? Are you using javascript to open the window or target="_blank"?

Comment: Have edited with the information you require, really confusing me this... Cheers.